# trouble with a step on proof of existence of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

On proof of existence of conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal{G})$, using Radon Nikodym theorem, there is a step that takes a random variable $X\geq 0$ a.s. and defines a measure $v(A)=\int_A X dP$ for all $A\in\mathcal{G}$.

Why is this a measure? I'm having troubles checking the axiom that takes $A_i\in\mathcal{G}$ a countable sequence of disjoint sets, then $v(\bigcup_i A_i)=\sum_i v(A_i)$.

So $v(\bigcup_i A_i)=\int_{\cup_i A_i}X dP=\sum_i \int_{A_i}X dP$.

I believe that I must use the dominated convergence theorem on the second equality but don't know how. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can use the Monotone convergence theorem. You need to find a increasing sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n \to X$ on $\cup_i A_i$.